# How to implement scanning of barcode from gallery in android

Tags: android, image, barcode, barcode-scanner

Here is what i have tried.

I have implemented Zbar Scanner in android application in which I can scan barocde and get result.

I have implemented [this](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) in my android project. now I want to implement scanner which scans images(of course Bar code images) from gallery. I know this can be possible anyhow. check [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_progetto2003.SCAN) link. It has barcode image scanning.

I have tried to search it out but failed. Please Help me out.

Comment: I think your question is not about barcode scanning, but how to read image files from media scanner?

Comment: @yushulx. Thanks for the comment. Actually I want to Decode the barcode images saved in SD card. I have successfully implemented Barcode Scanner via camera in my project.

Comment: I see. It's the only place (environment.externalstorage) for storing image data. Here are basic steps: 1, get the image path. 2, load the image to bitmap. 3, use RGBLuminanceSource to wrap the data for decoding.

Comment: @yushulx. Thanks for the suggestion. This works great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is possible now with the new [Barcode Scanning Apis](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html) available from Google Play Services 7.8 version. It has method to detect barcode passed as a bitmap.
Get path of image from gallery and convert it to bitmap and pass it like below:

```
     Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
     BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context)
                    .build();
if(barcode.isOperational()){
    SparseArray<Barcode> sparseArray = barcodeDetector.detect(frame);
                if(sparseArray != null && sparseArray.size() > 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); i++){
                                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Value: " + sparseArray.valueAt(i).rawValue + "----" + sparseArray.valueAt(i).displayValue);
                                        Toast.makeText(LOG_TAG, sparseArray.valueAt(i).rawValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                }else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"SparseArray null or empty");
                }

}else{
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Detector dependencies are not yet downloaded");
}
```

In your build.gradle file, include the following under dependencies section:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.+'

Following Manifest permissions are must:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Meta data for google play services:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Meta data for first time install/run time dependencies to be downloaded for getting barcode detector operational.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />
```

For detailed usage of this api, Refer [Github Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision), follow [Code Lab](https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes), [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/package-summary).